# Why is my cache manifest failing?

Tags: html5, cache, google-chrome

I have created the following cache maniest file-

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js
http://bharath.lohray.com/scripts/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js
http://bharath.lohray.com/scripts/jqui-ui-smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css
```

When I call it in my HTML Page, certain other resources fail to load without a 404 error. Below is the screen shot of the network tab from the chrome developer tools. removing the  `manifest="app.mf"` attribute from the `<html>` tag and clearing the application cache makes everything work as expected. What could be wrong?

[image: Network Tab from Chrome Developer tools]

Answer (score 1):

I just came across [this question StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902774/) and realized that I have to specify the resources not cached. Appending

```
NETWORK:
*
```

to my manifest file solved the problem.